# Is it possible to force the buttons of an AlertDialog to always display vertically?

Tags: android, button, android-alertdialog

I'm into building several AlertDialogs for Android, the buttons from this AlertDialogs in some mobile phones display vertically while in others horizontally.

In the ones that show horizontally there's the problem that not all text of the buttons might not display properly. As an example I'm showing this dialog for confirming a mobile phone number.

[image: Cancel not displaying correctly]

Where Ca is displayed it should show Cancel.

For this dialog I could make it bigger, but some of the others dialogs have text that is not going to fit even if done bigger.

If the buttons where to display vertically there would be no problem.

Is there any way to force that?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using custom ui for your dialog you can make your UI as you wish.
. If you are using linear layout to show buttons set weight as  1 for all 3 buttons so that all 3 buttons will equally split the space available. Otherwise you can place the button one below the other.